# 3D rigid body matching algorithm

Tags: 3d, sum, distance, lines, minimize

As can be seen in the picture below, I have a number of lines in 3D. They consist of 3 different groups of lines, and the common property of the lines in each group is that they pass close to the same point. However, in this problem, we don't know which line belongs to which group. What is given are only the 3D coordinates (x,y,z) of the 2 ends of all the lines.

[image]

My job is to find an algorithm to match/fit/register a triangle (a rigid body) to those lines such that the sum of distances between 3 vertexes of the triangle and their corresponding lines is minimized.

In conclusion, given a number of sets of (x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2) (which are coordinates of 2 ends of a line), I need to find the position of 3 vertexes of a triangle to fit in those lines (given the relative distance between the 3 vertexes).